# How to check if a wavefunction is continous or not? and how to find probability?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

How to find if the following function is continuous? how do I find its derivative? Also, how would I find the probability of finding the function at $x = a-2$ and $x = b+4$?

$$ \psi(x,0) =\frac{Ax}{a}, \ \ if \ 0 \leq x \leq a$$
$$ \psi(x,0) =\frac{A(b − x)}{b − a}, \ \ if \ a \leq x \leq b$$
$$ \psi(x,0) = 0, \ \ otherwise$$

Answer (score 1):

Both $\frac{Ax}{a}$ and $\frac{A(b-x)}{(b-a)}$ are polynomial functions which when graphed are functions that have no holes, no jumps or asymptotes and behave well with limits, etc. They are continuous functions on the real line. And for $0$ the function obviously only has one value over it’s domain so it is continuous as well.

To find the derivative of this wavefunction, just take the derivatives of each of the seperate rules.

As for finding the probability of $x = a-2$ and $x = b+4$, you must remember that $ΨΨ^{*}$ is not a function that gives you the probability for a particle being at any one individual point in space, it is a probability density, which means you can find the probability that a particle exists within a certain region of space, but not any one individual point. Technically speaking, there are an infinite amount of points in space so the probability of a particle being at any one point is actually zero. Note that contrary to popular belief a probability of zero does not necessarily equal impossible.

So if you want to find the probability for a particle being in one of those regions, simple integrate the probability density over that region.

Comment: ahh so for probability I should square Ax/a (since b+4 is 0 anyways) and integrate it with x=a and x=0, doing so simplifies my answer to a/b , but what do i do with this? i have x=a-2 and x=b+4  , how would i get a probability? wouldnt i get an answer in terms of x?

Comment: For the probability density for x to be within some range of x values between x = 0 and x= a you square Ax/a, and for the probability density for x to be within some range between x =a and x = b you square A(b-x)/(b-a). And the probability density is zero otherwise. If you were to integrate from say, x= a-2 to b+4, you would get an answer in terms of a and b, not in terms of x.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check the continuity at a and b.

Comment: how would it be in terms of a and b ? i got a/b so using the range given, wouldnt it be in terms of x? im sorry if i sound dumb im completely a newbie at this

Comment: @studentferret That’s okay, don’t worry about it. Basically, it doesn’t make sense for the probability to be in “terms of x” because the probability is calculated by evaluating the antiderivative of the probability density at the endpoints. So to calculate the probability for the particle to be within x= a-2 and x=a, you integrate A^2*x^2/(a^2) from x = a-2 and x=a (assuming a-2 is greater than or equal to zero)

Comment: @studentferret Remember x is just a variable; it could represent any value until you explicitly give it one in the integration. I think you’re expecting the probability to be in terms of the position variable “x” because intuitively you think we’re supposed to be calculating the probability of the particle being at any one point. Remember, we can only calculate the probability that the particle will be in a certain region of space.

Answer (score 1):

$\Psi^*\Psi=|\Psi(x)|^2$ according to the Born Rule is the **probability density function** $P(x)$, not the 'point probability' in $x$.

The probability of finding the particle in a part $\delta x$ of the particle's domain is  given by (for a normalised wave function):

$$P(x, \delta x)=\int_x^{x+\delta x}\text{d}x|\Psi(x)|^2$$

It is obvious that for $\delta x=0$ $\Rightarrow P(x, \delta x)=0$.

So  the *point probabilities* in the two points you're looking at is effectively $0$.

It's important to note this as many textbooks lazily abbreviate *probability density function* to *probability*. They are NOT the same.